# How do I evaluate the sum $\sum_{j=0}^d (-1)^j n^j \binom{d}{j}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Let $n>0$ be an integer. Let $d$ be a positive integer.

How do I show that $$\sum_{j=0}^{2d} (-1)^j n^j \binom{2d}{j} = (n-1)^{2d}?$$

Comment: This is simply $ (1-n)^{2d} $ by the Binomial theorem.

Comment: You're completely right.

Comment: Tag algebraic geometry?  abelian varieties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't this just the binomial expansion of $(1-n)^{2d}$?